# css selectors: difference between "body h1", "body .h1" and "body.h1"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to understand to what elements this css rule would be applied:

```
body h1, body .h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
    color: inherit;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
```

I understand `body.h1` but not `body h1` nor `body .h1`

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Best to do some reading.

Comment: + you dont need to select `body` as a parent, only  `h1 , .h1` is enough

Comment: thanks for the answers, I understand now. I just don't get why bootstrap uses `h1` as a class name, it can be confused with html `h1` element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`body h1` will address all `<h1>`-elements inside the `<body>`-element:

```
<body>
    <h1>This one</h1>
    <div>
        <h1>And also this one</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

`body .h1` will select all elements inside the body that have *the class* `h1`:

```
<body>
    <h1 class="h1">This one</h1>
    <div class="h1">And also this one</div>
</body>
```

`body.h1` finally will style the `<body>`-element itself, when having a class `h1`:

```
<body class="h1"></body>
```

Answer (score 7):

- `body.h1` will select the `body` element if it has a class of `h1`.

  - (ex. `<body class='h1'>this one</body>`)
- `body h1` will select all `h1` elements in the body.

  - (ex. `<body><h1>this one</h1></body>`)
  - this is redundant in well-formed HTML, it will basically do the same thing as `h1`, because the only place an `h1` element can be (if your HTML is well-formed) is in the body)
- `body .h1` will select all the elements that have the `h1` class in the body.

  - (ex. `<body><div class='h1'>this one</div></body>`)

Therefore, `body h1, body .h1` will select:

```
<body>
    <h1>this element</h1>
    <div class='h1'>and this one too</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

- `body.h1` selects `body` with the class of `h1`.
- `body h1` selects all `h1` elements anywhere inside the `body` element.
- `body .h1` selects all elements of any type with class `h1` inside of the `body` element.

The selector in your CSS is targeting all `h1` elements AND all elements of any type with class `h1` that are inside the `body` of your markup.

Answer (score 0):

**body h1**

it will find all h1 in your body

**body .h1**

it will find all elements with class h1 in your body

Answer (score 0):

`body h1` : All `h1` elements that are the descendants of the `body` element

`body .h1` : All elements  with a class `h1` that are the descendants of the `body` element

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/P2z5x/